One file cannot see .env variable in express
I have an express api (backend) inside a main folder with an .env file:
main
  - .env
  - backend

In app.js I can connect to my database using the .env variable like so:
const dbconnect = require("./data/db");
require("dotenv").config();

dbconnect();

However in another file (seeder.js) the .env file/variable isn't seen, so if I try:
const dbconnect = require("./db");
require("dotenv").config();

dbconnect();

I get:
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

My db file:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dbconnect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB);
        // await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/recipes");
        console.log("Database connected");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit();
    }
};

module.exports = dbconnect;

The bottom line is - app.js works but seeder.js doesn't work, why?

main/package.json (how I launch the app)

"scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "client": "npm run dev --prefix frontend",
        "server": "nodemon backend/bin/www",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
    },


Show you file system, for better understanding

Code doesn't contain the explanation for that. if seeder.js and app.js are on the same level (which is not shown), they work the same way. It's not shown where the root of the project. Please, provide a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

@EstusFlask I add an image with the file tree, does that help? If not, I'll push the whole thing to git and provide a link (it's not big).

This doesn't have enough detail to reproduce the problem.  How are you launching the program in each case?  Does the current working directory change?

If you launch one with node backend/app.js with CWD main but you launch the other with node seeder.js with CWD main/backend/data then it won't find the .env because it's in main/.env (which is a little weird -- I was expecting it in main/backend/.env)

@Wyck good question, and my mistake for not stating it. I launch it from the main folder, please check my edited question. Just tried moving it to backend, in that case seeder.js works but app.js doesn't. So right now I can have it work by having 2 .env files, one in main and one in backend, but I am not happy with this, I want it in main only.

In case CWD comes into play, you are free to adjust the way it finds the right .env, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#path

figured it out. node seeder works only if I have .env in both places, I had to add the command to package.json in main file in order to just have the .env file there - "data:import": "node backend/seeder",

Please make use of require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' }) syntax to locate your one-and-only .env file in the right folder.  (Please have only one .env file, but locate it correctly.)
You can use __dirname to get the directory name of the currently executing script if that helps.
How to get ~/main/backend/app.js to locate ~/main/.env
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.env') });

How to get ~/main/backend/data/seeder.js to locate ~/main/.env
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// note extra '..'
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '.env') });


Just import dotenv in db file like,
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

const dbconnect = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB);
        // await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/recipes");
        console.log("Database connected");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit();
    }
};

module.exports = dbconnect;


tried already, doesn't work
